# Как сделать форму которая имеет две кнопки + и -

Tags: html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такие кнопки рабочими???Помогите пожалуйста, а то уже все перепробовал что знаю

Comment: Будем очень рады увидеть что именно Вы перепробовали.

Comment: А ничего, что поисковик выводит первой ссылкой решение данной формы?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он из категории "Напишите код за меня" и "Мне лень самому искать решение"

Comment: Вовсе не лень написать самому код,если бы только умел пользоваться JQuery, но увы пока до него не дошел, только недавно начал JS учить, ну и я конечно же после того как спросил тут, нашел ответ уже в гугле где написано что нужно использовать плагины или же писать код самому.

Answer (score 3):

Стили сами накидайте

```js
$(function() {
  $("#plus").on("click", function(){
    $val = $("#amount").val();
    $("#amount").val(parseInt($val) + 1);
  });
  $("#minus").on("click", function(){
    $val = $("#amount").val();
    $("#amount").val(parseInt($val) - 1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="-" id="minus"/><input type="text" value="1" id="amount"/><input type="button" value="+" id="plus"/>
```

Comment: `:)24` улыбаясь ошибку шлёт :) Хватить зарабатывать репу на таких вопросах!

Comment: @Other хватит завидовать чужому успеху :))

Comment: Успех - это кривая реализация простейшей штуки на вопрос ленного юзера?

Comment: @Other в точку!

Comment: @tCode, товарищ, вы не правы