# Подскажите название JQuery плагина

Tags: jquery

Всем доброго дня. Подскажите кто-нибудь название подобного плагина как на изображении чтобы можно было подключить. А то сам пока на jquery писать не могу.
Вот изображение[image: Плагин]

Нужны кнопки.+ и -

Comment: Вам уже тут все пояснили: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633071/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8    Никакие плагины не нужны, вам дали полный jQuery код для кнопок

Comment: хорошо спасибо.Просто мне сказали что есть плагины готовые.